# Metamask stuck loading on startup, solutions as of 2023?

Tags: metamask, wallets

I'm sure many have run into this issue. With Metamask stuck loading " Connecting to Ethereum Mainnet". This problem has persisted for many years. it's 2023 already, what are some of the best ways of getting this unstuck and why does it get stuck in the first place?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too since I right-clicked Metamask extension icon and switched *This can read and change site data* to *On this site only*. Reverting back to *On all sites* and refreshing tab helped instantly.